# How to setup HyperV virtual machine to have static IP and have access to internet?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, vagrant

Is possible to setup **HyperV virtual machine** to have **static IP** and also have **access to internet** ? (on latest **Windows 10 Pro**)

To sum up, requirements are like so:

- virtual machine should have local (manually defined) IP like 192.168.1.18 (ideally defined from host computer, not in VM)
- virtual machine should be ideally accessible only from host computer *(not from public)*
- virtual machine should have access to internet *(from wifi adapter where must be defined DHCP)*
- would be great if Virtual Machine (guest) could stay in DHCP client mode

Machine is created by Vagrant but probably will need manual tweaking - as Vagrant [static IP bug is open here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8384).

*PS. I am web developer with basic understanding of networking, so please keep that in mind with possible explanations :)*

Comment: Yes. This is a very common configuration. Have you tried to set this up and are facing some specific problem?

Comment: Yea I've tried some things but ended neither not able to connect to VM, or not working network at all... :/ so I hoped someone was dealing with similar issue and can provide "dummy style" help. Will try again, and can post details later if no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  You'll use the guest operating system's network configuration utility to set the static IP address.  Make sure to include a default gateway and DNS Servers so you can browse the internet.

After that, it's just a matter of setting the firewall to only allow connections from the host machine and blocking all other inbound connections.

Comment: I was thinking that there is solution without modification of VirtualMachine (guest) - something what will say that virtual machine should be assigned this IP so guest can stay as DHCP client.. Which network interface switch should I use in your example ?

Comment: You'll want an external switch.  You can use a MAC address reservation within DHCP if you have access to the DHCP server.  You'll have to set a static MAC address and not just he dynamic one generated by HyperV.

Comment: But there might be one issue, if I type gateway and IP inside machine, will this solution work on all networks ? -- I am connected through WiFi adapter so my network is based on DHCP on place I work.. so host PC can have different IPs (& subnets) as one defined in guest machine...

Comment: If you connect to different networks, then a MAC address reservation won't help.  If you statically set a network address in the VM, it won't have access to anything on a different network.  Your host NIC would still be using DHCP, and thus would get an IP address properly.